# PowerPoint - How to display the Value from Slide 1 ComboBox in following slides?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to select a "Type" of presentation on the first slide, like "Private", "Public", "Confidential", etc. in an ActiveX Combobox and have the selected value show at the bottom of future slides in an ActiveX TextBox.

I have the Slide 1 Combobox working fine.  I run the presentation, get focus, pull-down and select my value.  It is ComboBox1.

I can't seem to find the trick to reference that Value in future slides.  Extremely novice in vb.  Not sure I'm using the PowerPoint vb editor properly.  Seems my code/values are just limited to the current slide and not future slides.

On slide 2 I have TextBox1 defined.  I can get it to take a value with TextBox1.Value = "This is a " & ComboBox1 & " slide."  But all that displays is "This is a  slide".  I've tried everything I can't find a way to reference that first slide ComboBox1 value but I can't.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Inserting source.

This is working on Slide 1.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then AddDropDownItems
MsgBox "Currently:" & ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Sub AddDropDownItems()
ComboBox1.AddItem "Private"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Confidential"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Secret"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Public"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Test"
ComboBox1.ListRows = 5
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus()
MsgBox "Changed to:" & ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

This is not working on Slide 2:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
TextBox1.Value = "Change: " & 
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value & 
"is the Type"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use `Option Explicit` in your code modules? If not, do you get an error because `ComboBox1` is probably out of scope?

Comment: I did not use Option Explicit.   Seems to be the case.  I will try.

Comment: Tried it.  Got an "Item ComboBox1 not found in the Shapes collection" using ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value as the field.  Should I make a new field equal to that before leaving Slide1?

Comment: revise your question to include the code you're trying to use :) makes it easier to assist

Comment: Revised.  Thanks!

Comment: There is Option Explicit at the top of Slide 2 as well.  Just missed the cut and paste.  Also, I tried ComboBox1.Value in slide two and it doesn't display.

Comment: Is the intention to have the ComboBox on slide 1 *set* the text in TextBox on slide 2? Because you're using the textbox `Change` event, but nothing in the code ever *changes* its value.

Comment: Yes, that is the intention.  For this test, I go into the TextBox to try to make a change and the TextBox does change to "Change: is the Type".   But that is the intent.  Maybe I shouldn't use a TextBox activex?  Maybe a Share with text embedded?  Seems like some googling is showing that as a possibility.  Or, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: the answer I posted is working as far as I understand your intent. this stuff only works in presentation mode afaik and if you're toggling in and out of that you may need to redo the combobox selection. these variables don't retain values beyond runtime of the event procedures, if you need to cache them then that must usually be done using other properties of the slides or shapes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to have the ComboBox on slide 1 *set* the text in TextBox on slide 2, then you need your code to do that. The `TextBox_Change` event won't fire unless you manually edit its text (I tested your code, and it works to that effect, but that's probably not what you want).  So, the problem is that you never assign any value to the `TextBox` on Slide 2.

You can probably remove the `TextBox_Change` event procedure on Slide 2, I suspect you have used that only for debugging purposes.

Use the `ComboBox_Change` event to assign the text to the TextBox object on Slide 2. Add this code in your `Slide1` module:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

To apply to all subsequent slides:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Call UpdateOtherSlides()
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateOtherSlides()
    Dim s as Long
    Dim text as String
    Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    For s = 2 to ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        On Error Resume Next 'In case no "TextBox1" exists on the slide
        ActivePresentation.Slides(s).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = text
    Next

End Sub
```

**NB**: `Option Explicit` is a way to *force* you to declare all variables. It won't compile string literal names against the `Shapes` of any worksheet, but it will prevent you from using a variable name like `ComboBox1` in a slide module where no such object exists.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're most of the way there and just need to know how to pull the selected value from the combobox, so:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Got an "Item ComboBox1 not found in the Shapes collection" error.  Trying with Option Explicit now.

Comment: Option Explicit didn't help with the "not is Shapes collection" error.  Maybe I'll try to add a variable in slide 1, make it equal to your expression and see if that is available in later slide.